# Por que se cicla un programa cuando mandó a llamar un método?

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos, método, map

El siguiente programa no marca errores de compilación pero solo le funcionan los metodos `darDeAlta(),darDeBaja()`, los otros métodos `consultas(),modificacion()` no funcionan bien pues cuando los mando a llamar, me aparece el menú de opciones: `System.out.println("[a]ltas" + "\n" + "[b]ajas" + "\n" + "[c]onsultas" + "\n" + "[m]odificaciones" + "\n" + "[s]alir");
        System.out.println("\n Seleccione una opcion");`
y si vuelvo a seleccionar alguna de estas opciones (m,c,s), me vuelve a mostrar dicho menu, es decir se cicla el código. Por que?

Como puedo solucionar este problema?

```
class Alumno {

private String nombre;
private int matricula;
private double calificaciones[];


Alumno() {
}

Alumno(String nombre, int matricula, double calificaciones[]) {

    this.calificaciones = calificaciones;

}

String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

int getMat() {
    return matricula;
}

double[] getCalif() {
    return calificaciones;
}

void setCalif(double calif[]) {
    calificaciones = calif;
}

}

public class Ejercicio{

Map<Integer, Alumno> alumnos = new TreeMap<>();

public boolean darDeAlta() {
    Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean b=false;

    double d[] = new double[5];

    System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del estudiante");
    String n = y.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Introduzca su matricula (de 5 digitos)");
    int m = y.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Introduzca las calificaciones: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduzca la calificacion");
        d[i] = y.nextDouble();

    }

    if (alumnos.containsKey(m)) {
        System.out.println("Esa matricula ya existe, ingrese otra matricula");

    } else {
        alumnos.put(m, new Alumno(n, m, d));
        System.out.println("Se han dado de alta los datos :)");
        System.out.println("Desea ingresar mas alumnos?");
        String s = y.next();
        if (s.compareTo("si")==0 || s.compareTo("no")==0) 
            b = true;


    }

    return b;

}

 public boolean darDeBaja() {
    Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean c;

    System.out.println("Introduzca la matricula del alumno");
    int m = y.nextInt();
    c = alumnos.containsKey(m);
    if (c) {
        alumnos.remove(m);
        System.out.println("Se ha dado de baja al alumno");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No existe esa matricula");
    }
 return true;
}

public boolean consultas() {
    Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean c;
    Alumno al = new Alumno();
    System.out.println("Introduzca la matricula del estudiante a buscar");
    int k = y.nextInt();
    c = alumnos.containsKey(k);
    if (c) {
        System.out.println("Los datos son:\n" +"Nombre del alumno: "+ alumnos.get(k) + "Calificaciones: " + al.getCalif());
    } else {
        System.out.println("El alumno no se encuentra");
    }
 return true;
}

public boolean modificaciones() {
    Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean c;
    Alumno al = new Alumno();
    double calificacionesNvas[] = new double[5];
    System.out.println("Introduzca la matricula del estudiante");
    int k = y.nextInt();
    c = alumnos.containsKey(k);

    if (c) {

        System.out.println("Cuales son las nuevas calificaciones? \n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.println("Introduzca la calificacion");
            double calif = y.nextDouble();
            calificacionesNvas[i] = calif;
        }
        al.setCalif(calificacionesNvas);
        System.out.println("Se han modificado las calificaciones correctamente");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No existe esa matricula");
    }
return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean bandera = false;

    Ejercicio e = new Ejercicio();

    do {

        System.out.println("[a]ltas" + "\n" + "[b]ajas" + "\n" + "[c]onsultas" + "\n" + "[m]odificaciones" + "\n" + "[s]alir");
        System.out.println("\n Seleccione una opcion");
        String opcion = x.next();
        if (opcion.compareTo("a") == 0) {
            bandera = e.darDeAlta();
        }
        if (opcion.compareTo("b") == 0) {
            e.darDeBaja();
            if (opcion.compareTo("c") == 0) {
                e.consultas();
                if (opcion.compareTo("m") == 0) {
                    e.modificaciones();
                    if (opcion.compareTo("s") == 0) {
                        bandera = false;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } while (bandera);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu caso yo usaría un bloque `switch`, el código queda mucho más claro que tantos `if ... else if`.

```
    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean bandera = false;

    Ejercicio e = new Ejercicio();

    do {

        System.out.println("[a]ltas" + "\n" + "[b]ajas" + "\n" + "[c]onsultas" + "\n" + "[m]odificaciones" + "\n" + "[s]alir");
        System.out.println("\n Seleccione una opcion");
        String opcion = x.next();

    switch (opcion) {

        case "a":
            System.out.println("código para a");
            break;

        case "b":
            System.out.println("código para b");
            break;

        case "c":
            System.out.println("código para c");
            break;

        case "m":
            System.out.println("código para m");
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("lo que quieras, si ninguna condición se cumple");
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Me parece más limpio el switch como bien mencionas, sin embargo me parece que sería importante hacerle entender y ver a la persona donde realmente estaba su error también

Answer (score 1):

Por que lo estás metiendo dentro del if

```
 if (opcion.compareTo("a") == 0) {
        bandera = e.darDeAlta();
    }
    if (opcion.compareTo("b") == 0) {
        e.darDeBaja();
        if (opcion.compareTo("c") == 0) {
            e.consultas();
            if (opcion.compareTo("m") == 0) {
                e.modificaciones();
                if (opcion.compareTo("s") == 0) {
                    bandera = false;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

así solo hará la comparación cuando opcion.compareTo("b") sea 0 y por lo tanto ya no entrará, deben estar afuera

```
if (opcion.compareTo("a") == 0) {
        bandera = e.darDeAlta();
}
 else if (opcion.compareTo("b") == 0) {
        e.darDeBaja();
}
else if (opcion.compareTo("c") == 0) {
        e.consultas();
}
else if (opcion.compareTo("m") == 0) {
        e.modificaciones();

}
else if (opcion.compareTo("s") == 0) {
      bandera = false;
}
```

como nota extra nunca igualas a  bandera como en los primeros procesos, no sé si eso sea necesario en tu código, ya depende eso de ti